# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flatbuffers' on conda

Tags: python, python-3.6, conda

I just installed `flatbuffers` for conda with the command

`conda install -c conda-forge flatbuffers`

However, if I run a python terminal and import flatbuffers, it says

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flatbuffers'`

The `which python` outputs what I expect, but just in case I created a virtual enviroment and installed everything again, with the same result. The package flatbuffers is in `conda list`.

How can it be that I have just installed the package, that I have made sure that it is installed, but even so I can't import it?

Edit: It seems that flatbuffers is not in the `site-packages` folder. Any idea why it hasn't been installed there?

Comment: You need to add conda's dist-packages directory to your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Actually, I have just gone to the `site-packages` folder and flatbuffers is not there O.o

Comment: that would be the environment's `site-packages`, actually, so it's under `/envs/<env name>/lib/site-packages`

Comment: @Damaru Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I think I ended up installing everything with pip3 and that worked

Answer (score 18):

the `flatbuffers` package is just the library and command-line utility. For the python packages you also need to install

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-flatbuffers
```